# MongoDB return distinct values based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to use MongoDb to return distinct values for `details.sub_ap_name` when searching `details.ap_name` is equal to `EVPN` however my search is returning all the unique values for `details.sub_ap_name`

Here is what my current query looks like. I have also tried some aggregate searches as well but those are also not working for me as well. Can someonle let me know what I might be doing wrong?

`db['test-data'].distinct("details.sub_ap_name",{"details.ap_name": "EVPN"})`

here is my data set

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("101"), 
    "details" : [
        {
            "run_date" : "2021-04-18",
            "ap_name" : "EVPN",
            "sub_ap_name" : "EVPN TOR"
            
           
        },
        {
              "run_date" : "2021-04-18",
              "ap_name" : "EVPN",
              "sub_ap_name" : "EVPN Mobility"
             
             
        },
        {
            "run_date" : "2021-04-17",
            "ap_name" : "Multicast",
            "sub_ap_name" : "Multicast Layer 2"

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/49vHHUNYn8K

Note- Add index on `details.ap_name` for performance

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

[$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)

> Returns an array of all unique values that results from applying an expression to each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key. The order of the elements in the output array is unspecified.

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

> Groups input documents by the specified _id expression and for each distinct grouping outputs a document. The _id field of each output document contains the unique group by value. The output documents can also contain computed fields that hold the values of some accumulator expression.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "details.ap_name": "EVPN" } }, // filter to reduce load on unwind
  { $unwind: "$details" }, // break into individual documents
  { $match: { "details.ap_name": "EVPN" } }, // filter
  {
    $group: { _id: "$details.ap_name", "sub_ap_names": { $addToSet: "$details.sub_ap_name" } } // add unique values
  }
])
```

Comment: @Matt Glad i could help :)